# How do I get Wurlitzer Electric Piano sound on my yamaha keyboard

Tags: keyboard, digital-piano

I really want to a strong accent (>) for the chords, so that they stand out from rest of the chord progression.
I'm playing a song with Electric Piano tone on my keyboard - YAMAHA PSR-S 670 and I really want the typical Wurlitzer Electric Piano sound on there.
Can I get it as an expansion pack by YAMAHA or by changing some tone settings??
If not that exact, how do I make the Electric Piano accent more stronger, to make it stand out??
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the 670 personally, but there's a full voice list at https://usa.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/467808/psrs670_en_dl_b0.pdf Search 'Piano' & also 'EP'. The Wurli will be there somewhere, probably in a couple of variants. There are 'only two' electric pianos really, the other being the Rhodes. Generally, the velocity curve can only be accessed globally. Look for 'touch sensitivity'

Comment: This page https://www.psrtutorial.com/forum/index.php?topic=51398.0 suggests some ways to get a Wurlitzer sound with a bit of initial bark.